How to refer to a resource (in src/resources in the working code) in a deployed Eclipse plugin?
I'm relatively new to developing Eclipse plugins and have a couple of files in src/resources that I'm trying to reference in the plugin I'm making currently. However, I can't seem to figure it out.
I've attempted the following methods to retrieve the resources:
MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/file_name")

MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/file_name")

MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("resources/file_name")

Bundle bundle = ResourcesPlugin.getPlugin.getBundle();
URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("/resources/file_name") )
InputStream is = url.openStream();
...

Bundle bundle = ResourcesPlugin.getPlugin.getBundle();
URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("resources/file_name") )
InputStream is = url.openStream();
...

None have worked, and I can't think of a quick way to determine what exception is being thrown and/or where it's being thrown from.
I'm not sure if it has any relevance, but the path for the plugin icon in the toolbar is /resources/<icon>. I suspect that image loading is different than resource loading, though.
Any thoughts as to where I might be going wrong with this?

When you build your plug-in, where does it physically end up in the jar?

@nitind The resources wind up in resources/<file_name>. resources directory is at the root of the JAR

In what way did that last one not work?

@nitind For the last one, the plugin died at the url.openStream() call. I can't see any errors in the Eclipse log, so I'm not sure what happened.

What was "url" in the debugger? I'm guessing null unless the ResourcesPlugin class is actually in your plug-in. Take care with which instance you're passing in there.

See https://vogella.com/blog/reading-resources-from-plugin/ (which works for me e.g. here).

@nitind The url appears to be valid when launching the plugin from Eclipse, but when I try exporting the plugin and installing it into another Eclipse instance, it does look like it's null.

@howlger. I notice there that you're effectively specifying an absolute path in the bundle.findEntries method. Do you think using absolute paths is the way to go here?

It depends which solution you choose. For MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(...) it's a relative path, e.g. if the qualified name of MyClass is com.example.MyClass then MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("file.txt") will look in the JAR for com/example/file.txt. Or MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("../../resources/file.txt") would mean resources/file.txt in the JAR. For single files I would recommend to put the file into the package next to the class and using MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("file.txt") to get an InputStream of it. For a directory structure, see the links.

The bundle you give to FileLocator must be the plug-in containing the resource - usually not ResourcesPlugin. See here and here

@howlger Would you care to write your most recent comment as an answer so I can credit you for the solution?

So, I wound up solving this, but the problem was an interesting one. One of the resources that I was trying to reference was a .java file, and that .java file was being compiled and thus no longer existed in the resulting JAR. Changing the extension to .txt got me around this.
That said, I did need to change the path I was using in MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream to ../../resources/file.txt, as per howgler's answer.
